# How to get .Net assembly (dll) information using java?

Tags: java, .net, dll

I would like to get .Net assembly (dll) file information using java.This is my sample .Net class

```
     namespace com.test
     {
             public class Testing
             {

             }

     }
```

So I would like to get this class name ('Testing') and other methods that included in this class using java.Is there any ideas or resources links?

Answer (score 0):

## Use *JNI* (**Java Native Interface**)

[Official Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)

#### From Wikipedia:

> The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call and be called  by native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages such as C, C++ and assembly